# Dynamic filter in calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I have to column in a calendar list: Department.

I want to dynamically filter below calender view based on above two combo boxes selections.

How can this be done?

[image: see the below screen shot]

Comment: did you solve this issue? I have the same problem which to me seems like it should be quite common but cant find any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using combination of jQuery and SharePoint OOB techniquest (for rendering the Departments).

For jQuery filters refer to my blog: [enter SharePoint List Filters using jQuery](http://sudhirke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/jquery-cool-filters-for-sharepoint-list/)

For updating your calender rendering (to include department),  you can use techniques from following articles

[SP2007 - Color Coded Calendar](http://sudhirke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/jquery-cool-filters-for-sharepoint-list/)

[Color Coded Calendars](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2008/11/sharepoint-color-coded-calendars.html)

I am not saying this is exact solution,  but it should give you enough idea to implement your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using "calculated columns" and some Jquery.

The following article explains how to filter using buttons (i.e. a button for each department) but this method could be modified to instead use a dropdown list like in your example.

I would probably recommend following the steps in the article to get it working first, then once it is working correctly you should be able to rework the HTML and Jquery to change it to a dropdown list instead of a list of links.

[Filter SharePoint calendar with Jquery](https://crm.webfletch.co.uk/posts/sharepoint-calendar-view-filter-on-a-single-calendar-for-office-365)