# I need to dynamically filter Sharepoint 2016 calendar. Is it possible?

Tags: filter, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I am using sharepoint calendar, but I am stuck at one scenario.
I have Team column in my sharepoint list, I need to dynamically filter calendar view based on selection of values in Team dropdown list.

Dropdown will be multiselect. It will have all team values from sharepoint calendar list.

The view displayed should be based on selection of dropdown values. I searched few post on sharepoint exchange itself but none of them had any answer.
[image]

Old similar question:
[Dynamic filter in calendar view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100481/dynamic-filter-in-calendar-view)

Any help will most appreciated.